# PySide/PyQt How to change text color for strings before appending them to QTextBrowser

Tags: pyqt, pyside, python-3.3, qstring

I'm writing a program  where I need to give any given string a color/highlight BEFORE adding it to the QTextBrowser. The string is stored in a variable so it doesn't seem to be possible to use HTML. 
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: My first question would be, why are you using QTextBrowser and not just QTextEdit?

Anyway, HTML is just a string anyway, but appending HTML won't necessarily work because it is outside of the <html><body></body></html> tags. You might need to use insertHTML() and textCursor() methods of your QTextBrowser/QTextEdit to insert the HTML code in the right place.

If you can clarify your question, it might be able to be answered. AT the moment I'm just guessing as to what your problem is.

Comment: insertHTML() worked. Not as I expected, but it did .